# PhoneGap 2.9.0 Plugin example

Tags: java, android, cordova

Hi i'm developing a simple app and i need send a text to Java but I have some problems doing that...

This is my BackEnd

```
public class Echo extends CordovaPlugin {
@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    Log.e("[Connection]", "Servidor não encontrado", null);
    if (action.equals("echo")) {
        String message = args.getString(0);
        this.echo(message, callbackContext);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I tried do the sample in phonegap docs but i got no luck

here is my funcion in JS

```
function echo(){
alert('Passed here');//this alert is working
    cordova.exec(function(winParam) {}, function(error) {}, "Echo", "echo", ['Hi']);
};
```

and my xml

```
<feature name="Echo">
<param name="android-package" value="net.gmlyra.Echo" />
</feature>
<!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->
<plugins>
<plugin name="Login" value="net.gmlyra.Echo" />
</plugins>
```

Anyone has a sample plugin to make clear how to do that ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Simply change in your JS File "Echo" -> "Login", "echo" -> "execute" and add finally the params you need: //String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext

```
function echo(){
alert('Passed here');//this alert is working
    cordova.exec(function(winParam) {}, function(error) {}, "Login", "execute", [args]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova.exec(function(winParam) {}, function(error) {}, "Echo", "echo", ['Hi']);
```

Echo in cordova.exec is service name, it must same with name="Echo" in plugin

```
<plugin name="Echo" value="net.gmlyra.Echo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<feature name="PushPlugin">
  <param name="ios-package" value="PushPlugin"/>
```

No need to write code on plugins tag. You already call